# Count of each words

Tags: java, regex, quoting

To write a java program to count the total number of words in a given string, and to print the count of each word in alphabetical order.

Using Collections, I need to sort and print the words in a given string with its corresponding count in the alphabetical order with some restrictions.

Words which are enclosed within the double quotes (eg."wrapped") should be sorted and printed at last.

Whenever I sort the list, words which are enclosed with double quotes are sorted first (based on ACII Table), but I need to sort all non-quoted words before double quoted words..

Please help me to find a solution for this type of sorting..

```
import java.util.*;

public class UniqueWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           String inp = sc.nextLine();
          inp = inp.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z'\" ]"," ");
          int count=0;
          char ch[] = new char[inp.length()];
           for(int i=0; i<inp.length(); i++){
               ch[i] = inp.charAt(i);
              if(((i>0)&&(ch[i]!=' ')&&(ch[i-1]==' '))||((ch[0]!=' ')&&(i==0))){
                  count++;
              }
           }
           System.out.println("Number of words "+count);
}
```

**Input:**

The implementation in a TreeSet is not synchronized in a sense that if multiple threads access a tree set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it must be synchronized externally. This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the set. If no such object exists, the set should be “wrapped” using the Collections.synchronizedSortedSet method.

**Expected output:**

Number of words 64

Words with the count

a: 3

access: 1

accomplished: 1

and: 1

at: 1

be: 2

by: 1

collections: 1

concurrently: 1

encapsulates: 1

exists: 1

externally: 1

if: 2

implementation: 1

in: 2

is: 2

it: 1

least: 1

method: 1

modifies: 1

multiple: 1

must: 1

naturally: 1

no: 1

not: 1

object: 2

of: 1

on: 1

one: 1

sense: 1

set: 4

should: 1

some: 1

such: 1

synchronized: 2

synchronizedsortedset: 1

synchronizing: 1

that: 2

the: 6

this: 1

threads: 2

tree: 1

treeset: 1

typically: 1

using: 1

“wrapped”: 1

**EDIT**
Got the solution....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is liable to downvotes since it asks us to write all of the code for you, which is too broad and not recommended. StackOverflow is a website where you ask questions about specific problems such as a particularly troublesome line of code or partial objective.

Comment: I think you can replace all non-alphabetic characters before sorting! For instance, if delete or replace " with space then you will not have a sorting problem.

Comment: As a practice too, wrote some code, but agree, specific issues be answered.

Comment: I'm sorry for not posting the problem with correct details.. As I am new to this I don't know how to post in a correct format. Next time I will try it better.. Thank you all for responding me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this code, update as required.
Leverage Collections feature and avoid writing code if the features are provided.
Try even improving on below code.

```
    String input = "This is a \"long\" statement.SortedSet Collections.";

    //split string based on your delimiters ( space, comma, dot )
    String[] split = input.split("[ ,.]");
    List<String> splitData = Arrays.asList(split);

    //create the data map with num occurances
    Map<String, Integer> dataToNumOccurances = new HashMap<>();
    for (String aString : splitData) {
        int occurrences = Collections.frequency(splitData, aString);
        dataToNumOccurances.put(aString, occurrences);
    }

    //convert to list so that it could be custom sorted
    List<String> sortedWords = new ArrayList<>(dataToNumOccurances.keySet());
    sortedWords.sort(new Comparator<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(String m1, String m2)
        {
            //apply the rule to push back double quoted string
            if (m1.startsWith("\"")) {
                return m2.compareToIgnoreCase(m1);
            }
            //apply case in-sensitive sort
            return m1.compareToIgnoreCase(m2);
        }
    });


    for (String word : sortedWords) {
        System.out.println("Word: " + word + ", count: " + dataToNumOccurances.get(word));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. :)  Now I got a clear understanding..

Comment: **For the Input:** The implementation in a TreeSet is not synchronized in a sense that if multiple threads access a tree set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it must be synchronized externally. This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the set. If no such object exists, the set should be “wrapped” using the Collections.synchronizedSortedSet method.        **->The word "wrapped" is not printed at the end.**

Comment: I found the solution....                                                                    
`ArrayList<String> sortedKeys = new ArrayList<String>(a.keySet());               
String rules = "<a<b<c<d<e<f<g<h<i<j<k<l<m<n<o<p<q<r<s<t<u<v<w<x<y<z<'\"'";
    Collections.sort(sortedKeys, new RuleBasedCollator(rules));
        
       for(String x: sortedKeys)
              System.out.println(x+": "+a.get(x));`